# SSH Keys set up and logs show successful, but still prompting for password?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, openssh, ssh-keys

This has never worked correctly I don't think. I can't recall, just have been inputting password all this time. I admin ten load balanced servers, but I am accessing them internally via internal ip's. When I ssh-copy-id my key to the remote system, it looks like it successfully authenticates, yet still prompts me for a password. My .ssh folder has perms of 600, only known_hosts has 644, and other servers that keys work on have the same perms. /var/log/secure says it was accepted. All perms in /etc/ssh/* are 644. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
**/var/log/secure**
Jul 25 07:30:55 X sshd[25970]: Accepted password for user from 172.29.2.133 port 23423 ssh2
Jul 25 07:30:55 X sshd[25970]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Jul 25 07:37:27 X sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Jul 25 07:37:27 X sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [user]
Jul 25 07:38:15 X sudo:   user: TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/less /var/log/secure

**ssh -v output**
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014                                                            
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config                                              
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 29: Applying options for *                                         
debug1: Connecting to X [172.20.2.131] port 22.                                              
debug1: Connection established.                                                                     
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1                                               
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1                                         
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1                                              
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1                                         
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1                                       
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0                               
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1                                                
Connection to X closed.                                                                      
Transferred: sent 11752, received 9832 bytes, in 262.0 seconds                                      
Bytes per second: sent 44.9, received 37.5                                                          
debug1: Exit status 0                                                                               
user@AUR-000229:/mnt/c/Users/user$ ssh -v X
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014                                                            
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config                                              
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 29: Applying options for *                                         
debug1: Connecting to X [172.20.2.131] port 22.                                              
debug1: Connection established.                                                                     
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1                                               
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1                                         
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1                                              
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1                                         
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1                                            
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1                                       
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1                                          
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1                                     
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0                                                
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8                              
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3                            
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4* compat 0x00000000                                         
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent                                                                       
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received                                                                   
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none                                                
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none                                                
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent                                            
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP                                                         
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent                                                               
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY                                                         
debug1: Server host key: RSA 8a:0f:76:f8:55:e7:65:25:10:ae:f3:d9:3c:dd:48:0a                        
debug1: Host 'X' is known and matches the RSA host key.                                      
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:10                                               
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct                                                           
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent                                                                       
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS                                                                  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received                                                                   
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent                                                               
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received                                                            
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password                                                 
debug1: Next authentication method: password                                                        
user@X's password:                                                                         
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).                                                        
Authenticated to X ([172.20.2.131]:22).                                                      
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]                                                             
debug1: Entering interactive session.                                                               
debug1: Sending environment.                                                                        
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8                                                              
Last login: Tue Jul 25 07:26:18 2017 from 172.29.2.133   



**Another server who with the same setup, keys work.**
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 29: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to X [172.20.2.132] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4* compat 0x00000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 15:5c:e0:96:15:6c:18:85:e8:e8:86:ab:3a:e7:7e:b7
debug1: Host 'X' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to X ([172.20.2.132]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Tue Jul 25 07:27:19 2017 from 172.29.2.133
```

Comment: Had a similar issues recently and it was because the user didn't own the authorized_keys file

Comment: My user does own the authorized_keys file, known_hosts, and the .ssh folder itself. I have run into the same things once, but have checked this one. All looks alright to me, but something must be off. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to contradict anyone, but if the server is only ever prompting for password authentication, your client won't offer a key.

In your debug above:

> debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
> debug1: Next authentication method: password
> user@X's password:
> debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
> Authenticated to X ([172.20.2.131]:22).

The server you're connecting to does not offer you (the client) to provide a PSK.  The server's sshd_config must have the following:

> PubkeyAuthentication yes
>
> AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

For comparison, this is my ssh debug output for a server the correctly is willing to accept publickey authentication:

> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>
> debug1: Offering RSA public key: imported-openssh-key
>
> debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 151
>
> debug1: Single to Multithread CTR cipher swap - client request
>
> debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).

-- sorry for poor formating --

Comment: I wasn't thinking config since sys administration is a diff department. I am in IT and am just another kind of linux sys admin that codes primarily and works with an application. This was the correct answer. Thank you!

#RSAAuthentication yes
**PubkeyAuthentication no**
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

As [Datmocc](https://superuser.com/users/131712/datmocc) suggests, check the ownership of the authorized_keys file on the server, as well as the ownership of the id_rsa file locally. You should also ensure only the owner has read permission (`chmod 400 <file>`). Take a look at the log output for sshd on the server when it starts up, it will complain if there is a problem with these permissions.

The debug log for your ssh session shows it is *not* providing the private key for authentication (as suggested in your question heading), and by the looks of it your server is not even advertising it will accept private key authentication. A debug log of a successful private-key authentication session should contain something like:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,**others
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 407
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

Until the server states `Authentications that can continue: publickey`, your client will never offer one.

Comment: I added logs for another server that ssh key login actually works. I was wondering if maybe the server wasn't properly set up for ssh keys as well. I don't see anything in the logs of the working server that I can compare. I do notice a line that says 'Server accepts keys X' which lists key formats it accepts. I wonder if the server isn't configured for rsa keys? I should check ssh setup possibly

Comment: In that log output: `Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password` is created from the server's response, not the client. Note that in your issue the word `publickey` is missing, showing that the server never offers it as a valid authentication means.